# Xamarin Forms error: Can't compile for iOS

Tags: android, ios, xamarin

I have created an application for Android and iOS with *Xamarin*.
All works with android, but with iOS I receive this error when I try to compile the code:

> Failed to resolve "Polenter.Serialization.SharpSerializerBinarySettings" reference from "SharpSerializer.PCL, Version=2.20.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"

Can someone help me?